# How to add up matched strings and then add up corresponding column totals?

Tags: google-sheets, transpose, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-sheets-query

I have a list of projects and the team members that are on each project.

I've added up the team `Count projects`...

[image]

### ideal result

How can I add up the project weeks for each team member?

- Ex: `cs` with total weeks (7 + 26 + 56) = `89`
- Ex: `ac` with total weeks (7) = `7`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({QUERY(QUERY(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(TRIM(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(
 IF(B2:F4<>"", "♦"&B2:F4&"♠"&B5:F5, )),,999^99)),,999^99)), "♦")), "♠"), 
 "select Col1,count(Col1) group by Col1", 0), "offset 1", 0),
 QUERY(QUERY(UNIQUE(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(TRIM(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(
 IF(B2:F4<>"", "♦"&B2:F4&"♠"&B5:F5, )),,999^99)),,999^99)), "♦")), "♠")), 
 "select sum(Col2) group by Col1", 0), "offset 1", 0)})
```

[image: 0]